# SQL nested sums with multiple joins and group by

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm not very familiar with SQLs. I'm using oracle. I met a question with over summing fields.

Here are the example tables:

```
A:
    A_ID
    A_NAME

B:
    B_ID
    A_ID
    B_NAME
    B_QTY
C:
    C_ID
    B_ID
    C_QTY
```

So the data structure is like A -> *B -> *C

I need to get the total quantities of Bs and Cs grouped by B_NAME and A_ID. For example:

```
A:
    A_ID    A_NAME
    1       A1
B:
    B_ID    A_ID    B_NAME  B_QTY
    1       1       B1  20
    2       1       B1  5
    3       1       B1  5
    4       1       B2  5
C:
    C_ID    B_ID    C_QTY
    1       1       3
    2       1       4
    4       2       2
    5       2       1
    6       3       1
    7       4       1
```

The expected result is:

```
A_ID    A_NAME  B_NAME  B_QTY   C_QTY
1       A1      B1      30      11
1       A1      B2      5       1
```

The 30 of B_QTY in the 1st line is result of 20 + 5 + 5.

The 11 of C_QTY in the 1st line is result of 3 + 4 + 2 + 1 + 1.

Here is my sql:

```
select a.A_ID,
    a.A_NAME,
    b.B_NAME
    sum(b.B_QTY),
    sum(c.C_QTY)
from A a left outer join B b on b.A_ID = a.A_ID
left outer join C c on c.B_ID = b.B_ID
group by a.A_ID
order by a.A_ID, b.B_NAME
    where a.XXXX = XXXXX;
```

So the problem is:

Since the B mapps to multiple Cs, the B_QTY will be summed multiple times. I'm not very familiar with SQL so I don't know if there is any simple way to distict the summing based on some fields (which is B_ID in my example). Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a better explanation of what you are trying to accomplish in the query.

Comment: Sample data and desired output could be a big help in explaining your problem.

Comment: Actually the tables are more than the example which will involve more tables in the group by.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can also be done like this:

```
WITH b2 AS
(SELECT b.*, sum(b.b_qty) over (partition BY b.a_id, b.b_name) b_qty_s
             FROM b)
SELECT a.a_id, a.a_name, b2.b_name, b2.b_qty_s, sum(c.c_qty) c_qty_s
FROM a JOIN b2 ON a.a_id = b2.a_id
JOIN c ON b2.b_id = c.b_id
GROUP BY a.a_id,a.a_name, b2.b_name, b2.b_qty_s
```

[Here is a sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/59066/1)

Answer (score 1):

I created an **[SQL fiddle for this problem](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/775c8/12)**.  The trick is that the B_QTY was appearing in your results more than once.  Summing on it was giving an artificially high value.  So instead, run a sub select to use the B_NAME only once!  Great question! :^D

A.B.Cade's answer is cool, but this solution will work for many databases. I've used this technique before with SQL Server, Oracle, and Informix.

Data/Schema:

```
create table a (A_ID int, A_NAME char(10));
create table b (B_ID int, A_ID int, B_NAME char(10), B_QTY int);
create table c (C_ID int, B_ID int, C_QTY int);
-- One dude
insert into a values (1,'Xiezi');
-- 2 orders? of 4 and 3
insert into b values (1,1,'B1',20);
insert into b values (2,1,'B1',5);
insert into b values (3,1,'B1',5);
insert into b values (4,1,'B2',5);
-- 2 order with 2 lines each.
insert into c values (1,1,3);
insert into c values (2,1,4);
insert into c values (4,2,2);
insert into c values (5,2,1);
insert into c values (6,3,1);
insert into c values (7,4,1);
```

SQL (The answer):

```
select a.A_ID,
    a.A_NAME,
    b.B_NAME,
    (select sum(b2.B_QTY) from b b2 where b2.B_NAME = b.B_NAME)
    as sum_b_qty,
    sum(c.C_QTY)
from a left outer join b on b.A_ID = a.A_ID
left outer join c on c.B_ID = b.B_ID
group by a.A_ID,
    a.A_NAME,
    b.B_NAME
order by a.A_ID
;
```

Output:

```
A_ID A_NAME B_NAME  SUM_B_QTY SUM(C.C_QTY)
1    Xiezi  B1      30        11
1    Xiezi  B2      5         1
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer and updating. The point is I need to aggregate the quantities based on a field of B. But the multiple joins is causing multiple times summing.

Comment: Does this answer your question?

Comment: Since actually my tables are more than this, I'm trying your solution right now... Will let you know if it works for me ;）

Comment: There should be another condition in the sub select since the B_NAME is not enough. I'm working on it...

Comment: Since in my real case, there are more than 6 tables joined together and the columns in the example are in different tables, it is easier to implement with @A.B.Cade 's solution. But I think yours should work, too. Thank you:)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A_ID,A_NAME,B_NAME,B_SUM,SUM(C_QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY A_NAME,B_NAME) C_SUM
FROM (
SELECT A.A_ID,A_NAME,B_NAME,B_ID,SUM(B_QTY) OVER(PARTITION BY A_NAME,B_NAME) B_SUM
FROM A JOIN B
ON A.A_ID=B.A_ID) T1 
JOIN C
ON T1.B_ID=C.B_ID
```

[image]

Comment: This is pretty much like @abcade answer

Comment: @Bassal, Actually there are some differences (2 window function instead of a group by, the joins are different and so on), though both solutions share the same basic idea of using a "sum over partition" in an inner query and joining this result instead of the original table

Comment: Oh.. I saw 'with' then stop reading the remain. @A.B.Cade is faster. This idea is basic..